# Reblog yourself on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

Recently in my timeline, I have seen users that have repeat posts from earlier such that it is in the format of a reblog.

[image: A tumblr post]

[image: Proof of a self reblog]

When I click on my posts I do not see the option to reblog.

How to reblog oneself on Tumblr ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reblog is mainly for re-posting blogs by others;

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/dashboard

> Reblogging lets you quickly share things you find on Tumblr. **Clicking the Reblog button next to any post will create a copy on your blog**, and give you a chance to include your own comments.
>
> Reblogged posts automatically **include attribution to the original poster**.

But you can reblog yourself by doing the following;

http://tumblring.net/how-to-reblog-yourself-on-tumblr/

> 1. Right Click on the following bookmarklet link – REBLOG YOUR OWN POST ON TUMBLR – and choose “Bookmark this link”
> 2. Now, once you are on one of the posts of yours that you want to reblog (not the dashboard, but the article itself ) Click on the Reblogging bookmark you just saved and you will be taken to the reblogging edition screen.

The bookmarklet mentioned above is;

```
javascript:%28function%28%29%7Bwindow.location=%22http://tmv.proto.jp/reblog.php?post_url=%22%20window.location%7D%28%29%29;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be dependent on a 3rd-party service, here is another way (harder, but needs only plain Tumblr):

1. search for `rk=` in the HTML source code (it's in the block opened by `<!-- BEGIN TUMBLR CODE -->`)
2. copy the value of this parameter (e.g. "1234" if you find `rk=1234`)
3. now manipulate the URL:

   1. append this value at the URL (add a slash before it, if there is none) (you can replace the slug with the value, if available)
   2. replace "post" with "reblog"
   3. remove the subdomain
4. call this crafted URL

---

EDIT: A few weeks ago, Tumblr updated their menu. Now it displays a "Reblog" link for your own Tumblr blogs (primary and secondary), too. However, you can't select to reblog in to the same blog you posted it on, so you'd have to select one of your secondary blogs. Since this update the described way doesn't seem to work anymore for the same blog; you can only reblog to your other blogs.